# Query to Android developers who is using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I'm a developer of an Android library which requires QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission at app targets Android 11 or higher.

There was a new policy from the Google Play store 2 years ago, they would enforce developers to submit a reason for using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. But the policy was postponed for 2 years, and now they restarted this policy.

Related Link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779

In this document, Google says this policy will block app updates from **12th July 2022**, if there is no declaration. But one of my customers got alert mail from Google, their app will be blocked from **4th May 2022** if they don't declare the reason for this permission usage.

My team is not managing the Android app, just managing the library, so we have not received similar mail at all. And also my other customers are not received similar mail yet.

Is there Android developers who have received a similar mail from the Google team? If you are, would you share the due dates of declaration to use the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission mentioned in your mail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons you cannot ask for QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. This will allows you to check or you can get all installed app in Phone.

If your app is like cleaner app or have feature like app manager, so for this kind of feature you can add QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES. You will need to show video of that feature which is using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES or need to give specific reason.

If your app only required to check any specific app installed or not then you can add like below.

```
//remove QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission and add like below
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" /> <!-- replace with your packagename --!> 
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
</queries>
```

I need to check whatsapp and business whatsapp installed or not. Same way you can added. And I think there no limit to check like above.

Same mail I also received, Before deadline date you need to give reason or update your app with I explained above.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I also know the basic requirements and steps to declare QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES. I wondered was the deadline from my customer was different from Google's official documents, so I need to know if this official deadline is 12th July or 4th May, or it is various for each developers.

Comment: I don't know deadline date is same for all or not, for me its showing 12th July. QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES is declared in your manifest file. And if you need this permission then explain why it requires in your app's play console > App Content > Sensitive permissions and APIs.

Comment: Thanks, so for you it was the same as the official deadline...

Comment: Yes right. Did you understand my answer? Hope now you know what changes you need to do.

Comment: Yes, actually my library is kind of vaccines, so need to use QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission to use my library. I'm creating guidelines as you said, recording video, and pagination flow at Play Console...Anyway, Thanks. I will make announce based on the official deadline 12th July.

Comment: @pratikvekariya, after above changes, is that ok if we ignore that mail?

Comment: If you have changed anything in your code then You will need to upload new apk and complete App Content > Sensitive Permission section. They will verify and if there is any issue you will receive mail or it will show in Console > Policy(above App content). If you didn't get any mail or any thing that means issue is resolved

Comment: @pratikvekariya my code is not using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, only uses <queries> element like you mentioned above but still received warning email about QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission. Do you know why? And how can I resolve id ?

Comment: its a warning, if you are not using QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES then nothing to do. That warning fired to all developers to keep in mind and if using then need to solve. But if you are not using then to worry.

Comment: @HanJungYoun where we need to upload video and pagination flow ? my apps doest use  QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission then also i have received this message and from one of my app i have removed this permission then should i reupload this app ?

Comment: You can check in your console > your app > App content > sensitive permissions

Answer (score 1):

I also received an email about this policy, but the paradox is that I do not need or use that permission, at least explicitly stated in the Manifest